# ASP.NET AJAX: Executing Javascript code before firing request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

How can you execute some JavaScript before an Ajax request happens? I'm already using the following;

```
function pageLoad() {
    var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    manager.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
}

function OnBeginRequest(sender, args) {
}
```

but that seems to be executing simultaneously to the firing of the request, and that's not helpful to me. Any thoughts, ideas? I also use JQuery so if there's some kind of an alternative that i could use please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There's another event that happens when you initialize the request, the [`initializeRequest` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397460.aspx).

Use it via `add_initializeRequest()`, like this:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    manager.add_initializeRequest(OnInitializeRequest);
}
function OnInitializeRequest(sender, args) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really help. MSDN site does say that begin request happens before the request and its good for animations, which is exactly what I'm doing. But is it possible that a JQuery animate function returns before the animation is actually complete?

Comment: @smkngspcmn - yes, it absolutely returns before it's complete, animation frames are on a 3ms timer, if you want to run something after the animation, use the callback function (available on every animation function) to kick it off.

Comment: Ok, but then i have to use the callback function to trigger the AJAX request instead, right? I haven't really found an easy way to do this.

Comment: @smkngspcmn - Either or, what is your actual problem here, the animations isn't...doing what correctly?

Comment: When a user initiates a postback i'd like to show an animation (ie: fadeout) and then fade back in on response. The problem is when the request happens before the animation(in this case a chain of animations) finishes, the whole thing ends up looking messy: i get strange flickers, the animation timing doesn't work correctly, etc. Hence i'd like to wait till the animation finishes and then fire request. Am i making sense?

Comment: @smkngspcmn - Yeah, though I wouldn't do this, I'd use `.stop()` on the fade-in portion if the request completes early, that way it'll stop and fade back in from the current value.  Also, be sure you're fading an element that's a parent, like a wrapper `<div>`, not an element that's being replaced as part of the postback